# Google Maps API Notify if Marker is Near Another

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google maps API to allow users to set a location by clicking on a map. Wherever the user clicks, the marker is placed and it works quite well. My problem is, my users are adding duplicate locations to my application despite the fact that they can visually see there's already a marker at that location (I'm loading markers for existing locations from my database).

**Is there a way, within the Google Maps API, to fire an event if a marker is placed within X distance of a marker already on the map?** I know I could probably use the haversine algorithm in javascript in some way, but I'd like to avoid that kind of complexity on the client side if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, which doesn't require any further calculating of distances or similar:

For every marker placed on the map also create a circle at the same position.
Hide the circle by setting fillOpacity and strokeOpacity  to `0` and apply a radius that fit's your needs.

Result: the circle is not visible, but still exists. The map will not respond to click-events when the user clicks on the hidden circle.

Comment: This was the perfect solution. I implemented it making the circle visible so the user has a visual cue that the area is already taken and it works really nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this method.. this may be require some modification based on your need, this will be client side but the logic can be implemented server side also.

```
function CheckIFMarkersAreNearBy(preExistingMarkersArray, milesToCheck, lat, lon){
    var range = milesToCheck/70;

    var minLat = lat - range;
    var maxLat = lat + range;
    var minLon = lon - range;
    var maxLon = lon + range;

    var markersNearBy = 0;

    for( var i = 0; i < preExistingMarkersArray.length; i++){
        if(preExistingMarkersArray[i].lat > minLat && preExistingMarkersArray[i].lat < maxLat && preExistingMarkersArray[i].lon > minLon && preExistingMarkersArray[i].lon < maxLon){
            markersNearBy++;
        }
    }

    alert('you have ' + markersNearBy + 'markers near by you current selection');
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, where you compare lat with maxLon: preExistingMarkersArray[i].lat < maxLon

Comment: thnx, made the changes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is specific function for that. The closest thing you will find is going to be [google.maps.geometry.spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#spherical) which includes a function to `computeDistanceBetween(from:LatLng, to:LatLng, radius?:number)`

So before you drop a new marker on your map just get the distance between your current markers and the newly requested one. Keep in mind, that even if Google Maps API provided way to do it, it would still be on the client side, so you would not be avoiding the "complexity on the client side" anyways.

Comment: I guess what I mean is that I'm trying avoid having to maintain that complexity on the client side myself (if it's already built in). I'm checking out your solution now (will mark answer if I can get it to work). Thanks.